# how to know which apps are downloading and recently opened for the first time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to get the information of currently downloading apps and apps which are recently opened for the first time. I have tried this with `SpringBoradService` framework but this is a private framework, and I want to submit it on app store.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of apps installed on the device using your app? Or you want to track the usage of an app?

Comment: I want to get a list of currently downloading apps and fist time opened app after download.

Comment: What do you mean by currently "downloading" apps? The downloading state is going to be for a very short duration and by no means can you access that info. You can get to know whether an App is installed or not.

Comment: @AkshatSinghal:: Do you have any idea how to know whether app is installed or not?

Comment: you need to use 'canOpenURL:` method go check whether the app is installed or not. You'd need to know the custom URI of the app for that.

Answer (score 2):

IOS have very fine grained permission set and do not allow application to read data about other application so simply its not possible. You can not use undocumented method as Apple says that they can change the implementation for bug fixing or by updating the SDK cause App crash. They do not allow the use of Private API and trace at submission at store. Mostly private method can be found in debugging at Xcode and start with _Underscore so you can try alternative to achieving things if you do not want to get reject your application later at submission.